# Handling persistent IDs in mapping to stateless gui model

Tags: model-view-controller, gwt, persistence, stateless

I have a GWT application at hand with a client-side GUI model optimized for display purposes. The GUI represents a business object tree retrieved from a SOAP service. Each object in the tree carries a UID I need to pass back to the service when persisting changes to the tree.

The application is supposed to be stateless.

The GUI model is considerably different from the tree I receive, i.e. entities in the GUI model do not map 1:1 to entities in the tree.

So far I have only a mapping strategy that allows me to map GUI model *types* to service model *types*, but I lack a mapping strategy for *instances*: When I retrieve two instances [1] and [2] of type A with UIDs 4711 and 0815 from the service and map them into instances of types X, Y and Z in the GUI model, I am able to map them back into two instances of type A, but not preserving the fact that UID 4711 belonged to instance [1] and UID 0815 belonged to instance [2].

If the application is to stay stateless, I guess I need a way to persist these UIDs and their relation to the GUI model entities on the client side. Is there a pattern or strategy to solve this challenge *without* giving up the - purposeful - incongruence between GUI model and service model?

Any hint appreciated. Mentioning of pertinent pattern names sufficient. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused - why does "stateless" mean "client can't know the IDs or do any sane mapping to them"? If there is no 1:1 mapping, is there at least a clear invertible function for object marshalling? Can changes to the 'stateless' objects result in a different number/type of persisted objects, and is it possible for such changes to clearly be mapped back to the original objects. Continuing in this line of thought, is it acceptable to just blow away the old persisted objects and build new ones? (also, what is instance 1 and 2? you mentioned only types A, X, Y, Z and the two uids)

Comment: OK, I'll try to clarify:

Comment: 1) The client (GUI model) *can* know the IDs, I just have no good design idea how to do this without having to change the GUI model so that it more resembles the service model 2) Yes, GUI entries can lead to the creation of new to-be-persisted entities (these would not carry an ID initially) 3) no, it's not acceptable to blow away the old persisted object instances. I have to build a history 4) example clarified in my original post

Comment: Can you give some examples in your question of what some of these rules for mapping types might look like? For example, is A always mapped to X with a Y child, or is B sometimes a W, and sometimes a Y? And can C be represented as a Z with an optional sibling U? This really doesn't seem like a GWT/mvc/persistence problem, but I'll try to give you some thoughts if you can flesh it out a bit. Adding more to the client side might actually help, by trying to maintain as much of the existing state as possible, but it would be helpful to have the problem in more detail. First thought: visitor pattern